# CSS z-index not working correctly when different media screen width set

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to sort out the z-index in my response webpage and I would appreciate your help... When the browser (Chrome, IE, take your pick) resizes to less than 961px (or any other media type set a specified width) the text reduces as per the style (tick!) but the z-index does not! Instead it places the id=content container behind instead of in front of the tagline element. I'm trying to create the effect of cutting off the legs of the text... it's a design thing.

Below is a snippet of code. The original code includes multiple media views (thanks again in advance).

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="eye-candy" style="background-color:yellow;height:100px"></div>
<div id="tagline">A cold beer sounds good right now!...</div>
<div id="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec commodo augue orci, porta mollis magna dapibus a. Nunc lectus lectus, tristique non felis vitae, eleifend volutpat felis. Praesent ante ligula, ultrices ut uscipit porttitor, eleifend eu purus. Cras a neque sem.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
#wrapper {
width: 100%;
}


@media only screen and (min-width:961px) {
#tagline {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    font-size: 3.125em;
    font-family: 'century gothic', georgia, sans-serif;
    color: blue;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    padding-left:5px;
}
#content {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    background-color:green;
    z-index: 10000;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width:960px) {
#tagline {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-top: -37px;
    font-size: 2.40em;
    font-family: 'century gothic', georgia, sans-serif;
    color: red;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    padding-left:5px;
}
#content {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin: -13px 0 0 0;
    text-align: left;
    background-color:green;
    z-index: 10000;
}
}
```

Comment: how about removing `overflow:hidden;` from `@media only screen and (max-width:960px) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-z-index), z-index is applied only to positioned elements (those with position: absolute, fixed or relative). So adding position: relative to #content should help.

Comment: Thanks Ilya, that was indeed the trick. Much appreciated! Nick

Answer (score 0):

I made some corrections : 
I hope it can help you  : 
Check this out :

http://jsfiddle.net/EnesTesla/kCgKB/embedded/result/

HTML CODE :

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="eye-candy" style="background-color:yellow;height:100px; margin-top: 100px">
<div id="tagline">A cold beer sounds good right now!...</div>
</div>
<div id="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec commodo augue orci, porta mollis magna dapibus a. Nunc lectus lectus, tristique non felis vitae, eleifend volutpat felis. Praesent ante ligula, ultrices ut uscipit porttitor, eleifend eu purus. Cras a neque sem.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE :

```
#wrapper {
width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:961px) {
#tagline {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    font-size: 3.125em;
    font-family: 'century gothic', georgia, sans-serif;
    color: blue;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    padding-left:5px;
}

#content {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    background-color:green;
    z-index: 10000;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:960px) {
#tagline {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-top: -37px;
font-size: 2.40em;
font-family: 'century gothic', georgia, sans-serif;
    color: red;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    padding-left:5px;
}
#content {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin: -13px 0 0 0;
    text-align: left;
    background-color:green;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Enes, but this did not work, as per the earlier post by Ilya I was missing position:relative from the #content container. But thankyou for your input. Nick

Comment: I haven't understood your problem very well :) Next time would be better :D